# Asp Password <input> fields and assigning to a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, passwords

I'm trying to take a input value from `Password<input id="txt_pwd" type="password" />` and assign it to a varible in codebehind file.

Eg: Like in text boxes

```
String x=this.txt_name.Text;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so what happens when you are trying?

Comment: It does not allow me to assign it. Like in the drop down.

Comment: What error you are getting? id of your password text box is `txt_pwd` and your code is using `txt_name`.? Did you notice that ?

Comment: Yeah that was the example like it works fine for texts and not for passwords. Anyways I figured it with few more tries. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: If this is asp.net webforms, on the element you need to add runat="server" **<input id="txt_pwd" type="password" runat="server" />**

Comment: Yup. I tried that and it worked @ngeksyo

Comment: @TonyStark cool, that glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was trying this few more times and all you can do is make this a normal text field `<asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />` like this and make add `input="password"` and it works fine.

E.g:
    `Password<asp:TextBox ID="txt_pwd" type="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>.`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It might help is you are using ASP.NET MVC that is.

**View**

```
<form action="Home/Login" role="form">
<input id="txt_pwd" name="txt_pwd" type="password"/>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
       string x = Request.FormData["text_pwd"];
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll refer this when I start the MVC developing.